# Puppeteer cookies not working with page.setContent()

Tags: cookies, puppeteer

I am unable to get Cookies to work in Puppeteer when using `page.setContent()`.

When I try to access Cookies I get an error `DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Access is denied for this document.`.

```
var filePath = path.join(__dirname, '../assets/index.html')
var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: "new",
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
  
await page.setContent(contentHtml);
await page.evaluate(async () => {
  // This throws an error
  // DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Access is denied for this document.
  console.log(`cookies`, document.cookie);
});
await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue by using

```
await page.goto(`file://${filePath}`);
```

Instead of `await page.setContent(contentHtml);`